# Mathematical proof that the covariance between two portfolios is $w_A^\top\Sigma w_B$

Tags: portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, reference-request, mathematics, covariance-matrix

How to prove in a line-by-line derivation that the covariance between two mean-variance efficient portfolios is equal to

$$w_A^\top\Sigma w_B$$

where $w_i$ is a unique portfolio weight vector, and $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix of asset returns.

Is there a source that goes over this in detail for portfolios in general, not just the minimum-variance and max Sharpe portfolios?

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far? You can easily show this by either starting from the definition of covariance for two portfolios whose return is defined as$\sum_i w_ir_i$ or you start from your equation and simply write it out.

Comment: Is the "covariance for two portfolios" the same thing as "the covariance matrix of asset returns"?

Comment: Hint: How would you compute the return covariance of portfolios $A,b$, i.e. $Cov(r_A,r_B)$? The covariance matrix belongs to the asset returns. A portfolio's variance is then driven by its weights in the single assets.

Comment: I guess you're saying they are not the same covariance, meaning $w_A^\top\Sigma w_B \neq w_A^\top\sigma_{A,B} w_B$. This would explain why the asset covariance doesn't make sense in the question's formula

Comment: You don't need efficient portfolios for this equation to hold. You don't even need anything finance related. Two (weighted) sums of random variables simply have the covariance as stated in your equation.

Comment: Covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is based on *asset return* vectors $r_1, r_2, \dots, r_i$. This is not the same as portfolio covariance which is based on *portfolio return* vectors $r_A, r_B$. Using these two different covariances are going to give very different answers, so they cannot be used interchangeably

Comment: I have the feeling we are in different languages. A good course of action could be for you to present what you have done or tried so far.

Comment: @develarist: If you take steveo america's nice answer and replace $w$ with $v$ ( IMHO,  it's clearer if  steveo america used variance below instead of covariance ), you get the variance of a portfolio with weights $v$.. The only difference between the two cases you referred to  is the first one uses the same return vector  when calculating the covariance matrix and the second one uses two different return vectors. In the end, you get a scalar in both cases.   Rudd and Clasing might be a good reference for this but it's been too long to be sure. I bet steveoamerica could give us a good one ?

Comment: @develarist: Note that, in terms of what I said above, it really would not be a useful improvement to call it variance in steveoamerica's example ( apologies to steveoamerica )  because the scalar that results in the case with two  of the same return vectors has a TOTALLY DIFFERENT INTERPRETATION than the one that results in the case where one uses two different return vectors. The point I was really trying to make is that the calculation is exactly the same in both cases, aside from the different return vectors.  My apologies for confusion.

Comment: if there is something in his answer that you think should be clarified, you could edit it with a note

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $x_i$ is the return of the $i$th asset, the returns of portfolio $\vec{w}$ are $\sum_i w_i x_i$. The covariance of the returns of two portfolios, $\vec{w}$ and $\vec{v}$ are then $$
\sum_i \sum_j w_i v_j \operatorname{cov}\left(x_i, x_j\right).
$$
Now note that $\Sigma_{i,j} = \operatorname{cov}\left(x_i,x_j\right)$. The rest is confirming that this expression is the bilinear form $\vec{v}^{\top}\Sigma \vec{w}$.